# How to insert dynamically added text boxes into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, sql-insert, html

I used `Javascript` to dynamically add `textbox` in order for the user to add more items in one process. Here's the code that add `textboxes`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    var item = document.getElementById('item');
    var serial = document.getElementById('serial');
    var property = document.getElementById('property');

    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {
        var input = document.createElement('input'),
        div = document.createElement('div');
        input.type = "text";
        input.setAttribute("name", "quant");
        div.appendChild(input);
        quantity.appendChild(div);

        var input2 = document.createElement('input'),
        div2 = document.createElement('div');
        input2.type = "text";
        input2.setAttribute("name", "items");
        div.appendChild(input2);
        item.appendChild(div);

        var input3 = document.createElement('input'),
        div3 = document.createElement('div');
        input3.type = "text";
        input3.setAttribute("name", "serno");
        div.appendChild(input3);
        serial.appendChild(div);

        var input4 = document.createElement('input'),
        div4 = document.createElement('div');
        input4.type = "text";
        input4.setAttribute("name", "proper");
        div.appendChild(input4);
        property.appendChild(div);

    };

</script>
```

When the user *clicks* the "**Add Text**" button, one set (four `textboxes`) will appear. My problem is even if the user clicks and inputs data into those `textbox`, it will only insert one set of data (which was the last set of input). Its because of the "name" of the `textbox` are the same. How can I insert those multiple data? Or how can I set a unique name for the added `textbox` in order to insert them into the database?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehx6M/
Here it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change the names with a `[]` appended to it. This will pass an array to the PHP on form submit.

```
input.setAttribute("name", "quant[]");
```

To get the values in PHP,

```
$quant_values = $_GET['quant']; // array of values 
$value_one = $quant_values[0];
```

You will need to implement a loop to iterate through the values.

Comment: I get the idea. Now, I want to know how to get the max number of array [] or what was the last number inside []. So I can compare with the for loop. Thanks

Comment: It's okay now. I used 
end($quant_values);
$compare=key($quant_values); 
to get the last set of array.